# загрузка по сети AltLinux в virtualbox

Tags: linux, altlinux

Коллеги, добрый день!
Прошу просветить по следующему вопросу.
Есть AltLinux Server. На нем развернут сервер сетевых установок.
Дальнейшем шагом должно быть развертывание AltLinux рабочая станция. По идее в среде Virtualbox для начала нужно создать саму виртуальную машину, а затем подгрузить к ней образ ОС, но тк загрузка должна быть по сети, то по логике в настройках машины никакие образы подгружать не надо.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как объяснить виртуалке, что она должна загружаться именно по сети.

Comment: https://yandex.ru/search/?text=pxe+virtualbox

Comment: В настройках сети выбрать "Сетевой мост". В "Системе" - "порядок загрузки".